# Merge many arrays to single

Tags: php, arrays

I am using array_push to put all arrays in single arrays with in foreach loop.

Like this :

```
$page_posts = array();
foreach ($userNames as $userName) {
    array_push($page_posts,json_decode(@file_get_contents($graph_url), true));
}
```

Now after loop i need this array in a single array, like if its producing :

```
array (array('0' => 'Item - 1'),array('0' => 'Item 0-1'))
```

to

```
array('0' => 'Item - 1','1' => 'Item 0-1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

```
$page_posts = array_merge($page_posts[0], $page_posts[1]);
```

EDIT:

To extend this functionality to multiple arrays within the original `$page_posts` you can do something like:

```
$flat_page_posts = array();
foreach( $page_posts as $post ) {
  $flat_page_posts[] = array_values($post)[0];
}
$page_posts = $flat_page_posts;
```

Comment: But how to do in loop ? I have not fixed number of arrays

Comment: Edited my answer. See above. :)

Comment: Careful, `array_merge()` will overwrite entries if identical keys occur. So the success of this depends on how the input data is structure, so on the structure of the json data which is not known here. For the second example I would suggest to leave away the key and instead _always_ construct a new array element out of the same reason.

Comment: OK, that's better. Thanks. Whereas that last edit made things worse again :-)